# Qt manually change the ratio between items in layout

Tags: qt, resize

I have two `QTreeView`s in a `QHBoxLayout`.

```
 <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="lay_disk_content">
  <item>
   <widget class="QTreeView" name="lay_disk_tvA">
 <property name="editTriggers">
  <set>QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers</set>
 </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
  <item>
   <widget class="QTreeView" name="lay_disk_tvB">
 <property name="editTriggers">
  <set>QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers</set>
 </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
 </layout>
```

When I resize the `QMainWindow` the two `QTreeView`s get resized with an 1:1 ratio between them. Now I would like to manually change it in the running program through dragging the space between them. This is somewhat a standard behavior but I don't get the name of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QSplitter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qsplitter.html)